# React Infinite re-render while passing setState hook function to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to update my state. I have declared :

```
const [s_groupes, setGroupes] = useState(
    initialGroupes.map(groupe => {
      return Object.assign({
        name: groupe,
        value: true
      })
    })
  )
```

From an array, and I wish to update this state when I click on a child component.
The problem is I don't know how to pass the function `setGroupes` to a child component.
I have no problem using `onClick={setGroupes}` on a button inside the same file, but I don't understand how to use it with props like this :

```
      <PieChart
        data={s_groupes}
        disableGroupe={click => disableGroupe(click)}
      />
```

where my function `disableGroupe` is :

```
  const disableGroupe = click => {
    let value
    const groupeClicked = s_groupes.find(groupe => {
      value = !groupe.value
      return groupe.name === click.data.value.name
    })
    const newGroupes = s_groupes.map(groupe => {
      if (groupe.name === groupeClicked.name) {
        return { ...groupe, value }
      } else {
        return { ...groupe }
      }
    })
    setGroupes(newGroupes)
  }
```

It seems to trigger too many renders but I don't get why. Also from consoles.logs it seems it "reset" my state every render.
I must add I'm using `on("click", e => return props.disableGroupe(e))` from the D3JS Library in the child component `PieChart` , the `e` returns actually something with `data.value.name` inside (but I'm not sure it's relevant)

Comment: Too many renders is usually caused by setting state in render which causes a re-render, which causes setting of state, and ends up in an endless loop. Start by removing the `disableGroupe` prop and then find what is triggering the method.

Comment: Yes I get that, the problem is I'm looking for an interaction between the state and the graph I created with D3. If I'm not using it I have no problem editing the state in the file I'm currently in. The whole thing is to pass a function that setGroupes (from useState) to a child component.

Comment: Can you show your PieChart component code? My guess is there is something calling this method there. Maybe it‘s defining the prop as a function call instead of a reference.